# Is there a way to project field of view lines outward to look for camera overlap?

Tags: camera, properties

I am configuring a camera arrangement in a room for a MoCap system. I would like to know beforehand whether or not every camera will have at least one overlapping camera FOV over the volume in which we are monitoring moving objects.

In Blender, assuming I know the camera's properties, can I extend the small pyramid representing the camera's FOV outward so that it projects all the way until it hits the wall? See image below for depiction of what I would like to try to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you simply need to increase the *Camera Size* property.

[image]

It will virtually extend a camera's view frustum taking into account FOV, offsets and any other properties.